# Is it possible to run a SQL Select statment on a CSV file?

Tags: sql, csv, select, sybase

Is it possible to execute a SQL Select statement on a CSV file on a Sybase Database?

```
Update DBA.user_data                                                     
set user_data.date_Sent = '12/16/2015'                                                      
where user_data.caseid in (select caseid                                                     
                       from DBA.cases
                       where cases.caseid=user_data.caseid
                       And cases.caseid in (select * FROM    'C:\\example\\test.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')));
```

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server? It looks like it given the syntax, but it's important to know.

Comment: No, Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Sybase.

Comment: Since Sybase doesn't seem to support OPENROWSET, I've removed my answer. A quick look on Google shows that Sybase has an "INPUT" statement and "load table". I don't know enough about them to provide any useful information on them or to attempt an answer, but they might be a place to start with a similar approach to what I had given for OPENROWSET.

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote and/or accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Sybase ASE, you can access flat files using the Component Integration Services (CIS).

I suggest you check out the [Component Integration Services User Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32702.1550/html/omni_ug/title.htm), which is part of the SAP/Sybase documentation.

Check out the section on [File system access: File Access](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32702.1550/html/omni_ug/omni_ug37.htm)

You will create a proxy (or existing) table, using the file information in the definition.

```
create proxy_table <table_name>
    external file at " pathname" [column delimiter “<string>”]
```

**OR**

```
create existing table fname (
    column1     int  null,
    column2     datetime null,
    column3     varchar(1024)  null
    etc. etc.
) external file at "pathname" [column delimiter “<string>”]
```

> Only the **select**, **insert**, and **truncate** table statements are supported
>   for file access. update and delete result in errors if the file proxy
>   is the target of these commands.

[Documentation: create proxy_table](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1550/html/commands/X32352.htm)

Comment: thanks, but I am not trying to import data to a table. I am trying to run a SELECT statement on the file. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @AllanJason The data is not imported unless you perform a SELECT INTO or Update w/ Select.  The proxy or existing table just provides the database with the necessary information to search through the file using SQL commands.

Comment: @Micheal Got you, I will give it a try. So a proxy table is a linked table? Or a virtual table that is created dynamically and not being saved?

Comment: @AllanJason I believe it's more of a non-materialized (not prepopulated) linked table, but I'm not exactly sure of how the engine implements it.